# Software to keep track track of attendance

Tags: web-apps, survey

There is an event each week with an entry fee. It's by donation so the amount each person pays is different. Also people can show up at any time.

At minimum, I would like to keep track of the amount of money donated, and how many people it paid entry for (usually a single person makes a donation but sometimes one may give a $20 and say it's for both of them).

What is a good tool for this? I was thinking Google Surveys but realized that might not be appropriate, as what I want is for when the "submit" button is hit, the data is recorded and the survey is immediately displayed again (so it's ready for when the next person arrives).

Comment: You could use some more description here. What is your purpose or goal?

Comment: @BasilBourque to keep track of data entered. I'm happy to give more description, what is it you're wondering?

Comment: Describe the [work-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow), the [use-cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case), how you intend to use the app. As it is now, your Question does not outline your requirements clearly.